# Javascript sort array with last item created

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to sort my arrays using this below condition

My json object:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T10:24:15.000Z",
    "complaintId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": true,
    "time": null,
    "complaintId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T10:53:14.000Z",
    "complaintId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "status": false,
    "time": "2018-03-05T11:58:45.000Z",
    "complaintId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T12:11:53.000Z",
    "complaintId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "status": false,
    "time": "2018-03-05T13:23:13.000Z",
    "complaintId": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T08:17:18.000Z",
    "complaintId": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T12:32:08.000Z",
    "complaintId": 2
  }
]
```

I have complaintId in my json,

i need to get json object of times with complaintId which located in last, for example there are many complaintId:1 in object.

i need to get only which have complaintId in last.

My expected output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T12:11:53.000Z",
    "complaintId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T08:17:18.000Z",
    "complaintId": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "status": true,
    "time": "2018-03-05T12:32:08.000Z",
    "complaintId": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and for each type of `complaintId` check if it doesn't `time` value, then update it or if the object has time value and then update the value corresponding to that `complaintId`.

```js
var data = [ { "id": 1, "status": true, "time": "2018-03-05T10:24:15.000Z", "complaintId": 1 }, { "id": 2, "status": true, "time": null, "complaintId": 1 }, { "id": 3, "status": true, "time": "2018-03-05T10:53:14.000Z", "complaintId": 2 }, { "id": 6, "status": false,"time": "2018-03-05T11:58:45.000Z", "complaintId": 1 }, { "id": 7, "status": true, "time": "2018-03-05T12:11:53.000Z", "complaintId": 1 }, { "id": 8, "status": false, "time": "2018-03-05T13:23:13.000Z", "complaintId": 2 }, { "id": 9, "status": true, "time":"2018-03-05T08:17:18.000Z", "complaintId": 3 }, { "id": 10, "status": true, "time": "2018-03-05T12:32:08.000Z", "complaintId": 2 } ],
  result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
    if(!r[o.complaintId] || !r[o.complaintId].time || o.time)
      r[o.complaintId] = {...o};
    return r;
  },{}))
  .sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id);
console.log(result);
```